# Cannot resolve .andExpect() method

Tags: java, spring, rest, testing, intellij-idea

I am implementing this test class taken from http://www.lucassaldanha.com/unit-and-integration-tests-in-spring-boot/

My IDE (Intellij) is not resolving the .andExpect() method.  I've searched the web but cannot find which jar or class this is part of. Can anyone help me out? Thank you.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ClientControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    CreateClientService createClientServiceMock;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Test
    public void testCreateClientSuccessfully() throws Exception {
        given(createClientServiceMock.createClient("Foo")).willReturn(new       Client("Foo"));

    mockMvc.perform(post("/clients")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(new     CreateClientRequest("Foo"))))
        .andExpect(status().isCreated())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", is("Foo")))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.number", notNullValue()));
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 19):

I understand that this is a very old thread, but in case anyone else runs into the same issue here's an answer. andExpect() needs to be moved outside of the perform() function's closing brackets.

Answer (score 1):

It's part of spring test framework.
Implements interface `org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions`

Maven artifact : [Maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test)